# How to get NULL if ON condition do not have matching data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have 2 tables in mysql. I want to JOIN them but even if no matching data from 2nd table, I need to show NULL but join them.

```
table1

id  |  name
-----------
1   |  name1
2   |  name2
3   |  name3
```

and second table

```
table2

id  |  service |  amount
------------------------
1   |  service1 |  10
2   |  service2 |  20
3   |  service1 |  20
4   |  service3 |  10
```

and the output I need is,

```
output

name  | amount
--------------
name1 | 10
name2 | NULL
name3 | 20
```

I have tried following query

```
SELECT t1.name,t2.amount 
FROM table1 t1  
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
WHERE t2.service=1
```

But it will not return name2 since there is no matching id in 2nd table. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean, no matching id? The ids 1, 2 and 3 are also in second table.

Comment: What is that where clause for ?

Comment: Please see the WHERE condition. I have given service id 1. So no matching data in 2nd table

Comment: @Ajit : Where clause is required. I need only service1 data, but need others as NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `where` clause turns your `left join` into an `inner join`*. Put the condition in the `ON` clause of your join

```
SELECT t1.name,t2.amount 
FROM table1 t1  
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
                   AND t2.service = 1
```

<sub>* You filter in your  `where` clause on data in your joined table. That forces the data to be filtered.</sub>